# .NET Core Cast to interface with generic type parameter of type which implements interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, interface

In .NET Core C#
I' trying something like this:

```
(IInterface<IParameter>)instance
```

Where instance is `new Implementation<Parameter>()`

And `Implementation : IInterface` & `Parameter : IParameter`

The issue is with the casting of the generic parameter. When I provide `Parameter` instead of `IParameter` it works but at compile time there is no way to know which type that implements `IParameter` will be used. All of these objects will be created via reflection.

So is there any way this cast works? Or some other way to implement this like providing no generic type parameter like you can with `typeof`.

**EDIT** Thanks to Ziriax

**A Fully Working Example:**

```
interface IInterface
{
    void Run(TInput input);
}

abstract class AbstractClass<TInput> : IInterface
    where TInput : IParameter
{
    public abstract void Execute(TInput input);

    public void Run(IParameter input)
    {
        Execute((TInput)input);
    }
}

interface IParameter {}

class Implementation : AbstractClass<Parameter>
{
    public void Run(Parameter input)
    {
    }
}

class Parameter : IParameter {}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object instance = new Implementation();
        var castInstance = (IInterface) instance;
        castInstance.Run(new Parameter());
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier

Comment: if you use `out` it resolves your issue except for the function (comment out the function and code runs). am still looking into the function

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
I forgot to add the `in` modifier. Since `TInput` is used as parameter i can't use the `out` covariant, or can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a non-generic interface too:

`interface IInterface
    {
        void Run(IParameter input);
    }`

And then let your generic interface extend this non-generic one.

Obviously your implementations should cast the `IParameter`, someone needs to cast it... You could make an abstract base class that does this for you, so not every implementation has to do this.

You might also be interested in the double dispatch pattern, although I'm not sure this will work in your case.

Comment: Yes you are so right! Thanks. A non generic interface and a generic abstract class works perfectly. I will post the full example shortly.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it now, this cannot work. Your `Implementation` class implements `IInterface<Parameter>`, so its `Run` method only accepts a parameter of the concrete `Parameter` type, whereas the `IInterface<IParameter>` requires that its `Run` method accepts an instance of *any* type that implements `IParameter`.

If the type of cast you're trying to do were allowed, I could define a different class that implements `IParameter`, e.g.:

```
public class DifferentParameter : IParameter { ... }
```

And then do:

```
castInstance.Run(new DifferentParameter());
```

But your `Implementation`'s `Run` method can't take `DifferentParameter`!

.NET therefore prevents you from performing the cast itself.

There are situations in which this kind of cast is allowed - if your interface were instead to be defined as:

```
interface IInterface<out TOutput>
    where TOutput : IResult
{
    TOutput Run();
}
```

By making the generic parameter `out`, it makes the interface **covariant**. This restricts the use of the type parameter as the result of method calls, but for covariant interfaces, casts like yours *are* allowed.

You can find plenty of documentation on both covariance and contravariance in the [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index).

Comment: The main thing I need to be the same is the `Run` method It needs to take a specific type as a parameter and I would not like to have to cast the parameter within the function. Also at compile time of the Main method I can't possibly know what the specific types can/will be. Can you think of any way of accomplishing this?